# Is it possible to use Spring Cloud AWS for connecting to an on-premise S3 compatible storage?

Tags: amazon-s3, minio, spring-cloud-aws

Is it possible to use Spring Cloud AWS (Spring Cloud AWS Core / Spring Cloud AWS Context) to connect to S3 on-premise (such as Minio/SwiftStack) that support full S3 API?

In short, the URL for S3 service needs to be framed within my application logic instead of the spring cloud AWS building the default based on region.

Answer (score 3):

The application can provide its own `AmazonS3` bean, configured to connect to the on-premise S3-compatible storage service.

This works because the Spring Cloud configuration code is configured to not create its own `AmazonS3` bean if one is already provided by the application.  Therefore, if the application provides its own `AmazonS3` bean, that bean will be used as the S3 client instead of the default.

I'm using Spring Cloud AWS to access Amazon's AWS in the running application, and a [Dockerized MinIO](https://hub.docker.com/r/minio/minio/) for integration tests.  I've configured my test's `AmazonS3` bean based on [sample code in MinIO's documentation](https://docs.min.io/docs/how-to-use-aws-sdk-for-java-with-minio-server.html).  This approach should also work for your situation of connecting the actual application to MinIO.

#### MinIoConfiguration.java

```java
import com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class MinIoConfiguration {
    @Value("${cloud.aws.credentials.accessKey}")
    private String awsAccessKey;

    @Value("${cloud.aws.credentials.secretKey}")
    private String awsSecretKey;

    @Value("${cloud.aws.region.static}")
    private String awsRegion;

    @Value("${my-app.aws.service-endpoint}")
    private String awsServiceEndpoint;

    @Bean
    public AmazonS3 amazonS3() {
        return AmazonS3Client.builder()
                .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(awsServiceEndpoint, awsRegion))
                .withPathStyleAccessEnabled(true)
                .withClientConfiguration(new ClientConfiguration().withSignerOverride("AWSS3V4SignerType"))
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey)))
                .build();
    }
}
```

#### application.yml

```yaml
cloud:
  aws:
    credentials:
      accessKey: MY_ACCESS_KEY
      secretKey: MY_SECRET_KEY
    region.static: us-east-1

my-app:
  aws:
    service-endpoint: https://example.invalid:9000
```

Comment: How to override the way the bucket subdomain is formed? In our on-prem S3 it isn't https://bucketname.endpointname.com, and instead endpointname.com/bucketname

Comment: @dukethrash Does calling `withPathStyleAccessEnabled(true)` (or the equivalent `enablePathStyleAccess()`) on the builder do that?

Comment: Yes but not using a property. You have to override the setup of AmazonS3. I've submitted a feature request to add pathStyleAccess as a spring cloud AWS configuration. https://github.com/awspring/spring-cloud-aws/issues/183

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You should be able to. I have tested cloudfoundry with S3 compatible blobstore MinIO as blobstore. You can install MinIO server and change endpoint instead of S3 quickly.

Comment: How do I configure a new endpoint? 

The only properties that I see available are these:
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/reference/html/appendix.html

Comment: You can refer to below blogs on how to access s3 client with minio and backend. Please let me know.

https://blogs.ashrithgn.com/spring-boot-uploading-and-downloading-file-from-minio-object-store/

https://docs.min.io/docs/how-to-use-aws-sdk-for-java-with-minio-server.html

Comment: None of those address how to use a third party AWS service with Spring Cloud AWS/the Spring Cloud config, but rather how to access it through normally configured AWS or Minio beans.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to below blogs on how to access s3 client with minio and backend. Please let me know.

https://blogs.ashrithgn.com/spring-boot-uploading-and-downloading-file-from-minio-object-store/

https://docs.min.io/docs/how-to-use-aws-sdk-for-java-with-minio-server.html

Comment: None of those address how to use a third party AWS service with [Spring Cloud AWS](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-aws)/the Spring Cloud config, but rather how to access it through normally configured AWS or Minio beans.